# Не работает запись в файл txt

Tags: php

Учусь по книге разработке на php. Там есть такой код

```
<?php
$fh = fopen("testfile.txt", 'w') or die("Создать файл не удалось");
$test = <<<_END
Строка 1
Строка 2
Строка 3
_END;
    fwrite($fh, $text) or die ("Сбой записи файла");
    fclose($fh);
    echo "Файл 'testfile.txt' записан успешно ";
?>
```

При запуске файл создается, но в него ничего не записывается, не пойму почему, права на создание, запись вроде есть.

Comment: `$test` и `$text` это так и должно быть?

Comment: блин, вообще не заметил опечатку эту, спасибо вам)

Comment: Ошибка в названии переменной $test (замененить на $text нужно)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавлю ответ для справки, запись и чтение из файла можно производить с помощью функций `file_put_contents` и `file_get_contents`;

Примеры:

1. Запись в файл

   file_put_contents('test.txt', 'testing string')
2. Запись в файл с блокировкой

   file_put_contents('text.txt', 'testing string',  LOCK_EX)
3. Запись в файл в конец уже имеющегося

   file_put_contents('text.txt', 'testing string', FILE_APPEND)

Comment: Да, согласен. Сам использую. Очень удобно.

Answer (score 4):

```
$fh = fopen("testfile.txt", 'w+');
$test = <<<_END
Строка 1
Строка 2
Строка 3
_END;
fwrite($fh, $test) or die ("Сбой записи файла");
fclose($fh);
echo "Файл 'testfile.txt' записан успешно ";
```

[Здесь инфа](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.fopen.php) по fopen.